# tar unpack and file/folder time

Tags: date, tar

A linux (busybox) device has no  real time clock (so after booting it is 1970).
I upload a tarball to this device. 
I want to take over the date of files which are in the archive, so that file date is that one from the archive.
Found, that this doesn't works, if system time is lower than archive time. 
As a workaround it is possible to set the date to future is possible, than files get the archive time.
BUT: the subfolders get the (future) system time, not time in archive.

Is there any chance to prevent this, so that files AND folder get archive time?

Comment: And you are using which: operating system? tar version?

Comment: Sorry for missing info: tar is from busybox, OS is an older linux 2.6.33